# Uncaught ReferenceError: person4 is not defined

Tags: javascript, uncaught-reference-error

From my code below, I try to remove a person that does not exist in my array. However, I provided an else statement to render when that person does not exist. I still get a reference error thrown. Can anyone help me out, I'm new to js. thanks.

```
class Employee {
  constructor(name, salary, hireDate) {
    this.name = name;
    this.salary = salary;
    this.hireDate = hireDate;
  }

  getInfo() {
    return `${this.name} $${this.salary} ${this.hireDate}`;
  }
}
class Department extends Employee {
  constructor(name) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.employees = [];
  }

  addEmployee(person) {
    if (person instanceof Employee) {
      this.employees.push(person);
    } else {
      console.log("The input is invalid");
    }
  }

  removeEmployee(person) {
    let index = this.employees.indexOf(person);
    if (index > -1) {
      this.employees.splice(index, 1);
    } else if (index === -1) {
      console.log("This person isn't in the department");
    }
  }

  calculateSalary() {
    let total = 0;
    this.employees.forEach((item) => {
      total += item.salary;
    });
    console.log(total);
  }

  printAllEmployees() {
    this.employees.forEach((item) => console.log(item.getInfo()));
  }
}

let accountsDept = new Department("Accounting");
let person1 = new Employee("David", 2000, "01/01/2020");
let person2 = new Employee("Mike", 1800, "04/02/2020");
let person3 = new Employee("Mary", 2100, "04/03/2019");
accountsDept.addEmployee(person1);
accountsDept.addEmployee(person2);
accountsDept.addEmployee(person3);
accountsDept.removeEmployee(person4);
accountsDept.printAllEmployees();
accountsDept.calculateSalary();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you call `removeEmployee` and pass it a value which isn't in `this.employees` then you will will the line `console.log("This person isn't in the department");`.

You **aren't** calling `removeEmployee`.

---

> ```
> accountsDept.removeEmployee(person4);
> ```

This line does two things:

1. It reads the value from the variable `person4`
2. It calls `removeEmployee` and passes that value to it

… except that `person4` doesn't exist, so step 1 throws the exception you are seeing and the code never proceeds to step 2.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I didn't consider the fact that it first checks the array.

Comment: It *doesn't* check the array first. That's the point.

Comment: @Martin you absolutely can not write `person4` out of the blue in any program (not just here, or in JavaScript, but ever). This is the only time it occurs in your code, and JavaScript simply can't tell what it's supposed to be - it won't take guesses, like *"ah yes, it must be a fake `Person` object"*. For testing the `"This person isn't in the department"` message you still have to provide something what exists for JavaScript. Even `accountsDept.removeEmployee(0);` would work, or an explicit `undefined`, like `accountsDept.removeEmployee(undefined);`

Comment: Of course creating `person4` for real, just not adding it would also work, so `let person4 = new Employee("Fake", 2100, "04/03/2019");`, followed by `accountsDept.removeEmployee(person4);` would trigger your check properly.